# i want to change my API response to become array of array object in laravel

Tags: laravel

i have a problem for the response, i want to change the response API because i need for my mobile APP, the feature have filter object based on date. So i hope you all can help me to solve the problem

i wanna change the response for my API

before:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "user_id": 1,
            "title": "gh",
            "date": "2022-02-10 13:05:00",
            "deskripsi": "gfh",
            "created_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:56.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:56.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "user_id": 1,
            "title": "ghf",
            "date": "2022-02-17 16:05:00",
            "deskripsi": "fghf",
            "created_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:12.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:12.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "user_id": 1,
            "title": "fgh",
            "date": "2022-02-17 18:05:00",
            "deskripsi": "gh",
            "created_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:40.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:40.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

here is the code for the response API above

```
return response([
            'tasks' => Task::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('date','>',NOW())->orderBy('date','asc')->get(),
        ],200);
```

and i want to change it my response API into this response

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "date": "2022-02-10",
            "task": [
               {
                  "id": 7,
                  "user_id": 1,
                  "title": "gh",
                  "date": "2022-02-10 13:05:00",
                  "deskripsi": "gfh",
                  "created_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:56.000000Z",
                  "updated_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:56.000000Z"
               },
               {
                  "id": 7,
                  "user_id": 1,
                  "title": "gh",
                  "date": "2022-02-10 15:05:00",
                  "deskripsi": "gfh",
                  "created_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:56.000000Z",
                  "updated_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:56.000000Z"
               }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-02-12",
            "task": [
               {
                  "id": 7,
                  "user_id": 1,
                  "title": "gh",
                  "date": "2022-02-12 13:05:00",
                  "deskripsi": "gfh",
                  "created_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:56.000000Z",
                  "updated_at": "2022-02-09T06:05:56.000000Z"
               }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `groupBy` on the resulting `Collection` from the query (see docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby)

For example, you could do:

```
$tasksGroupedByDate = Task::where(.......)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(fn (Task $task) => $task->date->format('Y-m-d'));
```

(Note: above uses PHP 7.4 arrow functions. Also, add a date cast on the `date` column in your `Task` model to be able to use `->format(` directly on the date field)

The above code results to:

```
{
  '2022-01-01' => [
    { Task object },
    { Task object },
    { Task object },
  ],
  '2022-01-02' => [
    { Task object },
    { Task object },
    { Task object },
  ],
}
```

(used Task object for brevity, but that will be `['id' => 1, 'title' => 'Task name', .....]`)

To morph that to the structure you want, you can use [map](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map) and then [values](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-values) to remove the keys and turn it back to an ordered array:

```
$tasksGroupedByDate->map(fn ($tasksInGroup, $date) => [
    'date' => $date,
    'task' => $tasksInGroup
])->values();
```

If you want to combine everything into one method chain:

```
return [
    'tasks' => Task::where(......)
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(fn (Task $task) => $task->date->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->map(fn ($tasksInGroup, $date) => [
            'date' => $date,
            'task' => $tasksInGroup
        ])
        ->values(),
];
```

Comment: This is much better.

Comment: Yeah, I gonna admit, this answer is much better than mine. The laravel collections groupBy is pretty powerful. If run into php version issues, or don't have access to date format, can easily use `->groupBy(function($item, $key){ return strtok((string)$item->date, ' ');}` But otherwise the last block of code with everything chained together would work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a human friendly date field based on the date column, then group by it.

While solutions do exists to accomplish this at the database level, I believe you'd still need to loop around it again afterwards to get the hierarchy structure you're looking for. I don't think it's too complicated for PHP to loop through it.

My suggestion is as follows:

Before:

```
return response([
            'tasks' => Task::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->where('date','>',NOW())->orderBy('date','asc')->get(),
        ],200);
```

After:

```
$out = [];
$tasks = Task::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->where('date','>',NOW())->orderBy('date','asc')->get();

foreach($tasks as $task) {
    $date = strtok((string)$task->date, ' ');
            if (empty($out[$date])) {
                $out[$date] = (object)['date' => $date, 'task' => []];
            }
            $out[$date]->task[] = $task;
}

$out = array_values($out);

return response(['tasks' => $out], 200);
```

Note in the above I'm using the function [strtok](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php). This function might look new even to the most senior of php developers.... It's a lot like explode, except it can be used to grab only the first part before the token you're splitting on. While I could have used explode, since the latter part after the token isn't needed, strtok is better suited for the job here.

Comment: Your answer is good. But it would be better to use Laravel collection, even if possible using sql queries.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I struggled enough with trying to format it to the desired output, lol. I'm sure there's a clean way to write it in laravel, but I'll let someone else come up with that. But if ya'll have the time to think of a way to write it cleaner, go for it. Aiming for getting it working here. Maybe in the future can clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$task = Task::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('date','>',NOW())->orderBy('date','asc')->get();

foreach($task as $item){
   $date[] = item->date;
   $result = Task::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('date','=', $date)->get();
}

return response([
   'tasks' => 
      ['date' => $date,
      'task' => $task]
],200);
```

maybe something like this

Comment: What is `getdatequery`?

Comment: query to get date only

Comment: so, where the query? It's just a string

Comment: Also, your syntax error `=>`

Comment: I mean replace it with your query or eloquent to get date field only

Comment: We recommend using the comments column if you only provide suggestions, not answers.

Comment: I appreciate that. But OP want group by date. Did you notice?

Comment: oh sorry I did not notice that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).